# How to popup ContextMenu in ListBox programmatically on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a ListBox in my page, I want some items in the ListBox can popup ContextMenu when you long press it, and **some items don't**, how can I implement this requriment programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. Define your Item's class with some information about popup:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
    // Menu attached or not
    public bool OptionsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

In XAML you will have to define your *ListView* (or *ListBox*) with apropriate *ItemTelplate*:

```xml
<ListView Name="myList" Holding="myList_Holding">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info}" FontSize="24" Margin="7">
                   <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                   <MenuFlyout>
                       <MenuFlyoutItem Text="First option"/>
                       <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Second option"/>
                   </MenuFlyout>                                       
                   </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
           </TextBlock>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then upon *Holding event* you can check *OptionsEnabled* property if to show a menu,if yes then do so:

```cs
private void myList_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.OriginalSource == null || !(e.OriginalSource is TextBlock)) return;
   TextBlock listItem = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
   if (listItem.DataContext == null) return;
   Item itemData = listItem.DataContext as Item;
   if (itemData.OptionsEnabled)
       FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(listItem);
}
```

A working sample you can [download here](http://1drv.ms/1ERQ4Ns).